# dynamic data in a div to be centered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how can I make a data align centered I am unable to explain it properly so I will paste the code here.

```
<div class"mainDiv">
  <ul>
      <li><dl> <dt> dynamic name </dt> <dd> dynamic value  </dd> </dl></li>
      <li><dl>
                    <dt>dynamic name</dt>
                    <dd>dynamic value</dd>
                </dl></li>
      <li><dl>
                    <dt>dynamic name  </dt>
                    <dd>dynamic value</dd>
                </dl></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The main div will be 100% width and the li's will contain dynamic data I want the ul to be centered no mater what data comes in. If I add one item it should be centered and if I add 3 items it should be centered. I have tried it. But my solution is giving the ul a fixed width and that is not solving my problem because the data is dynamic and keeping the width fixed is not a solution.

```
 <style>
  ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
  }
  body {
color:#fff;
margin:0; padding:0;
  }
  .main {
  background: #000000;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }
  .main ul {
  width: 100%;
  }
  .main ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  }
  </style>
```

I have added styles and also when I add these data types I get into problems.

Comment: You have to post your style rules here.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:

```
<div class"mainDiv" style="margin:auto;text-align:center">
  <ul>
      <li>dynamic data</li>
      <li>dynamic data</li>
      <li>dynamic data</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to main div as margin:0px auto; + text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

You could set the li to have

```
display: inline
```

And the ul to have

```
text-align: center
```

to align the list elements as a normal centered paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class"mainDiv" style="text-align:center;">
 <ul>
  <li>dynamic data</li>
  <li>dynamic data</li>
  <li>dynamic data</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you require to vertically center also.

Here is a great article for centering elements: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Also,

A working example with the vertical align: http://jsfiddle.net/eEakL/

CSS:

```
.mainDiv
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: table;

}
ul { 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one more style rule

```
.main ul li dd{
     margin:0;   
}
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7AmG/)